# How to permanently disable the live photo setting on an iPhone 13 Pro?

Tags: iphone, photos, settings, camera

How to permanently disable the live photo setting?

The "live photo" option is turned on in the preserve settings menu, but live photo turns itself on every time I turn it off in the camera app.

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I believe you're doing the correct thing. However, let me restate exactly how it should be configured. I have tested to ensure this works in iOS 17:

- Open Settings > Camera > Preserve Settings
- Switch "Live Photo" to **ON** position to **preserve** settings across launches
- Open Camera app and turn off Live Photos by tapping the Live Photo icon in the top-right corner. A diagonal line should appear.

If this procedure is not working, then something is malfunctioning on your phone. I am not aware of any specific procedure to make such a malfunction cease. Ensure you've installed all software updates, etc and try restarting your phone and repeating the steps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to permanently disable Live Photo for all future photos, you can change the default camera settings. Here's how:

1. Go to Settings:
   Open the Settings app on your iPhone.
2. Scroll down and tap on "Camera":
   Find and tap on the "Camera" option in the Settings menu.
3. Toggle off "Live Photo":
   Locate the "Preserve Settings" section and toggle off the switch next to "Live Photo."

---

I was able to verify this procedure on iOS 17.2.1 with an iPhone 12 Pro